# Checking if Generic Type Inherits from Generic Interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a base interface, IResponse...

```
public interface IResponse
{
    int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    int PageCount { get; set; }
}
```

...a generic interface, ICollectionResponse, which inherits from the base interface...

```
public interface ICollectionResponse<T> : IResponse
{
    List<T> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

...and a class, EmployeesResponse, which inherits from the generic interface and, subsequently, the base interface...

```
public class EmployeesResponse : ICollectionResponse<Employee>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is here. I have a generic task method that returns an instance of the base interface, IResponse. Inside this method, I need to determine whether T implements from ICollectionResponse.

```
public class Api
{
    public async Task<IResponse> GetAsync<T>(string param)
    {
        // **If T implements ICollectionResponse<>, do something**

        return default(IResponse);
    }
}
```

I have tried all versions of the IsAssignableFrom() method with no success, including:

```
typeof(ICollectionResponse<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: What should happen if a type implements `ICollectionResponse` multiple times for different `T`?

Comment: The simplest thing I can think of is `typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollectionResponse<>))`. The fact that this is ugly and can return multiple instances is a sign that you may want to rethink this approach. For example, you could just hunt for a public `Collection` property of an appropriate type -- this also requires reflection, but without the thin veneer of "type safety" (which you don't have anyway, in this case -- you cannot statically cast to `ICollectionResponse` because you don't know the type parameter).

Comment: Good question. Any subsequent implementations of the interface would have to be done explicitly. This _shouldn't_ happen and if it did it would be a special case. However, it should probably be taken into account and each version `Collection` handled.

Comment: It should be possible to use a generic abstract class in place of the generic interface to prevent multiple inheritance.

Comment: typeof is generally better be used during the compilation. Since you are going to be using runtime to define the type T, you should probably go with GetType() - since it works better with runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have any instance of `T` reflection must be used.

```
if (typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Any(
  i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollectionResponse<>)))
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Do something for {param}");
}
```

`IsGenericType` is used to find any generic interface - in this example it filters out `IReponse` which is also returned by `GetInterfaces()`.

Then `GetGenericTypeDefinition` moves from `ICollectionResponse<Employee>` to `ICollectionResponse<>` which is the type we want to check for. Because we don't know what `Employee` is.

As pointed out in the comments, there could be multiple interfaces implemented, such as `ICollectionResponse<Employee>, ICollectionResponse<Person>`. The code above will run the "Do Something" statement and don't care about if there's one match or many. Can't say if that is a problem or not without knowing more of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
List<bool> list = new List<bool>();

foreach (var i in list.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
  if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
  { }
}
```